# Prove that every tautology of the form (α → β) can be broken into (α → γ) and (γ → β), where the variables in γ aren’t in exactly one of α and β

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, first-order-logic

Given a tautology of the form (α → β), where α and β are propositions, I want to prove that there exists another proposition γ such that (α → γ) and (γ → β) are both tautologies, and that γ can only use propositional variables that are either in both α and β, or in neither of them (so can't be in only one of them).

I approach this problem by first noticing that all truth assignments can be broken into 4 cases based on the truth table for logical implication. Since (α → β) is a tautology, we can eliminate the case where α is T and β is F as that's impossible to occur. The other case we don't need to consider is where α is F and β is T, since in this case any proposition can be γ.

Left with the two cases, I need to find γ that will be true when both α and β are true, and false when both are false. I noticed that for an arbitrary truth assignment, there must be a set of variables that are true and are in both alpha and beta, and another set of variables all false and in both alpha and beta. I tried to use this observation but soon realized that different truth assignments can be very different yet giving same results, so I don't think this observation would help. I need some suggestions on how I should proceed.

Comment: Welcome to the site! When I was given this exercise, it came with the hint "Suppose $A$ is a propositional formula and $p$ is a letter appearing in $A$.
Explain how to find formulæ $A_1$ and $A_2$ not containing $p$ such that $A$ is logically
equivalent to $(A_1 \land p) \lor (A_2 \land \lnot p)$". It was also just after an exercise about proving the existence of conjunctive normal forms...

Comment: @IzaakvanDongen Intuitively I see what you mean but I'm not sure how to formally do it though. Can I say that given an arbitrary truth assignment with n propositional variables, we can break it into the column for p and the other columns, and we should be able to express the 4 cases: p false A true, p false A false, p true A true, and p true A false, and since {∨,∧,¬} is functionally complete, any proposition can be expressed into $(A_1 ∧ p) ∨ (A_2 ∧ ¬p)$?

Comment: You can certainly prove this by thinking about semantics - ie the truth table. Your argument seems fine to me! This argument does require the completeness theorem for propositional logic, though. You can also prove by purely syntactic means that every formula is equivalent to a conjunction of disjunctions of formulas of the form $p$ or $\lnot p$ where $p$ is a primitive proposition (which gives you a constructive proof). Either way, the fact I gave should follow.

Comment: @IzaakvanDongen Thanks!